# Microsoft teams deep link from chat

Tags: reactjs, debugging, microsoft-teams, deep-linking

I have a working deep link ([https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/c38259cb-cd15-4797-b634-098bcea43f9a/index1?webUrl=https://google.com/&label=Google&context={%22subEntityId%22:%20%2239138959%22}](https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/c38259cb-cd15-4797-b634-098bcea43f9a/index1?webUrl=https://google.com/&label=Google&context=%7B%22subEntityId%22:%20%2239138959%22%7D)). It work if I search it through Chrome, but if I send it into a team chat or just a chat in Microsoft Teams and click on it, it doesn't save the subEntityId param and I can't use it.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because your `context` is web encoded, which could be why it works in browser but not in Teams itself. Try this instead:

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/c38259cb-cd15-4797-b634-098bcea43f9a/index1?webUrl=https://google.com/&label=Google&context={"subEntityId":39138959}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still doesn't work because I after I copied the link into the chat it automatically converts to this: https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/c38259cb-cd15-4797-b634-098bcea43f9a/index1?webUrl=https://google.com/&label=Google&context={%22subEntityId%22:39138959}. And it doesn't work if I click on it

Comment: I managed to try it with this https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/c38259cb-cd15-4797-b634-098bcea43f9a/index1?webUrl=https://google.com/&label=Google&context={"subEntityId":39138959} but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, was just an idea. What do you mean though when you say "doesn't work" - can you elaborate?

Comment: I solved the issue by using the getContext function in my react app. Thanks for your help!

Comment: ah ok great, glad to hear